# Show node/add/* form in modal

Tags: drupal, modal-dialog

I have tried `lightbox2` and that did not work as desired, `modal_forms` does not show `node/add/*` form. Custom code that I found also not working as desired. Any experience or suggestions? All I want is a just the `node/add` form, for whatever I am trying to create, in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are after. [ctools modal](https://gist.github.com/mrconnerton/1979037)

This uses the ctools modal to display the node form.